# I get 403 "NotAllowedException" when using meteor with getstream stream.js to add activity

Tags: getstream-io

I keep getting the response below when i try to add an activity to my stream client side:

```
module.exports {offset: 145, readable: true, _events: {…}, statusCode: 403, headers: {…}, …}
body:
code:17
detail:"You do not have permission to perform this action."
duration:"0.00ms"
exception:"NotAllowedException"
status_code:403
__proto__:Object
caseless:Caseless {dict: {…}}
headers:{content-type: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"}
offset:145
readable:true
request:Request {_events: {…}, _maxListeners: undefined, body: "{"actor":"JamesAgwa","message":"This is a sample p…"verb":"post","object":"user:1","foreign_id":"1"}", signature: "user1 UgGaoBfBoazmPhfxkln_O3NDC1I", headers: {…}, …}
statusCode:403
toJSON:ƒ responseToJSON()
_events:{close: Array(3), ready: ƒ, error: Array(2), end: Array(3), data: ƒ}
__proto__:Stream
```

I keep getting: "You do not have permission to perform this action."

This is the client side code:

```
// client side instantiation of the stream service
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import stream from 'getstream';

const client = stream.connect('9uw2mdcxjhzh', null, '29400');
const ActiveUser = client.feed(
 'user',
 `${Cookies.getJSON('loggedInUser') ? 
 Cookies.getJSON('loggedInUser').profile.name.split(' ').join(''): 1 }`,
 'UgGaoBfBoazmPhfxkln_O3NDC1I',
);

export default ActiveUser;
```

The above code is then imported and used as so:

```
ActiveUser
  .addActivity({
    actor: this.state.currentUser.profile.name.split(' ').join(''),
    message,
    verb: 'post',
    object: 'user:1',
    foreign_id: '1',
  })
  .then((data) => {
    evt.target.reset();
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.response);
    evt.target.reset();
  });
```

Comment: Hey James - this looks like an authentication/authorization thing. Can you also share your client-side code that's making the calls into stream?

Comment: Ken - i just updated the question with the client side code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks James - it looks like that feed token (`UgGaoBfBoazmPhfxkln_O3NDC1I`) is hard coded in. Is that something that you included just for the example, or is that a generated thing?

Comment: Got the feed token from the 5 minute trial tutorial, since it uses my credentials when running the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you should generate a new client-side feed token regularly. I'm not sure how often those tokens expire. (Hypothetically, using the same token from the "Try the API" page *might* work, but I'm not sure. Best practice is to just generate that new token regularly.)

You can find docs on how to generate a client-side token here: https://getstream.io/docs/#realtime

Comment: Trying it out. Thanks Ken